# LibGDX game dies with PVRSRVAllocDeviceMem error in Android

Tags: java, android, textures, libgdx

I made a really simple game using the latest stable LibGDX. It's just a few Actors (5 max at any given time) and some background textures.

The game runs fine and after a few times that I die and have to start over I get the following message in the console

```
02-24 08:19:10.478: E/IMGSRV(26860): :0: PVRSRVAllocDeviceMem: Error 1 returned
```

The game continues running fine for a few seconds or minutes, then it just dies with no other error message in the console. The only other messages I see are GC ones.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Update:
Here's a screenshot of the heap right after I get the error message, but hasn't crashed yet:

[image]

Comment: Can you please give us more details.

Comment: Sure, what kind of detail would be helpful? The console only shows normal GC messages, besides the message included above.

Comment: Are you using an old android device? it's probably a GPU problem.

Comment: It's a [Samsung Galaxy Nexus](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_nexus_i9250-4219.php)

Comment: try to change your android testing device. https://code.google.com/p/skia/issues/detail?id=764

Comment: Added a screenshot of the heap. Also, I'm using GL2.0. Should I try 1.0 instead?

Comment: But you have to remember that size of the textures should be power of two.Try to use small textures and don't forget to dispose after use. good luck.

Comment: Are you using Linux for testing you app?

Comment: @daniel No I'm testing on a Galaxy Nexus. It works fine when running on a desktop.

Comment: I had very similar problem on Linux, when my audio device set to graphic card audio, this maybe happen on android, check the audio, sounds weird, but it worth to take a look.

Comment: Looking at a similar case. This link (https://code.google.com/p/playn/issues/detail?id=111) indicates it can be a threading issue (i.e. cleaning up GL stuff from outside of the GL thread).